SwiftUI canvas crash when trying to call firebase current user
I am trying to call the Firebase current user on main screen appear and the canvas crashes. But at runtime everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.
 .onAppear{
            let authUser = try? AuthManager.shared.getCurrentUser()
            self.showAuth = authUser == nil
        }

here is my auth manager
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

struct AuthDataResultModel {
    let uid: String
    let email: String?
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.uid = user.uid
        self.email = user.email
    }
}

@MainActor
final class AuthManager {
    //TODO: change dependency injection
    static let shared = AuthManager() //
    private init(){}
    
    //MARK: developer signIN
    func creteNewUser (email: String, pass: String) async throws -> AuthDataResultModel{
        let authDataResult = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass)
        return AuthDataResultModel(user: authDataResult.user)
    }
    
    func signOut () throws {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    func getCurrentUser() throws -> AuthDataResultModel {
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        return AuthDataResultModel(user: user)
    }
}

using Xcode 16.0
when I delete  this line of code canvas build fine
let authUser = try? AuthManager.shared.getCurrentUser()

is it a bug of Xcode version?
